# Serializing only some properties of parent and children to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Supposed I have two classes like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Child
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If I want to serialize some properties of Parent I can do like this:

```
var data = GetListOfParents();
return Json(data.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name}));
```

If I want to get the list of parents as above but each Parent contains one list of Children with selected properties like `Id` and `Name` only, what is the proper way to do it?

I don't want to use `[ScriptIgnore]` because my entities contain a lot of Properties.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
data.Select(x => new
    {
        x.Id,
        x.Name,
        Children = x.Children.Select(y => new
            {
                y.Id,
                y.Name
            })
    });
```